# How to install EGit for Anypoint Studio 3.5.1

Tags: eclipse, mule, egit, mule-studio

I have installed the version 3.5.1 of Anypoint Studio (for Mule ESB development). This version of Anypoint Studio appears to be based on Eclipse 3.8 (propably 3.8.2)

I want to install EGit, but encountered some problems.

Using the following download site in the 'Install new software' window:

http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates

i selected Eclipse Git Team Provider (including all sub modules) for installation, and clicked the 'Next' button.

I then get this error:

```
    Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Task focused interface for Eclipse Git Team Provider 3.4.1.201406201815-r (org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group 3.4.1.201406201815-r)
  Missing requirement: Git Team Provider UI 3.4.1.201406201815-r (org.eclipse.egit.ui 3.4.1.201406201815-r) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Task focused interface for Eclipse Git Team Provider 3.4.1.201406201815-r (org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group 3.4.1.201406201815-r)
    To: org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.ui [3.4.1.201406201815-r]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: EGit Mylyn UI 3.4.1.201406201815-r (org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.ui 3.4.1.201406201815-r)
    To: package org.eclipse.egit.ui [3.4.1,3.5.0)
```

How can i resolve this problem?

I hava a feeling that i should install an older version of EGit, since Anypoint Studio is based on a rather old version of Eclpise.

I see [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ#What_versions_of_Eclipse_does_EGit_target.3F) that this version of Eclipse should propably have EGit version 3.3.1, but how do I find and install this version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `http://archive.eclipse.org/egit/updates-3.3.1` as the download site in 'Install New Software'

If you need another version, see also [older versions of Egit.](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ#Where_can_I_find_older_releases_of_EGit.3F)

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar error. Older versions refused to install as well. I tried installing first Mylyn from [latest](https://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/downloads/) and it worked.